# Need to setup and access web disk for a hosting account

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, ubuntu

I am on linux(ubuntu 12.04) and have purchased a hosting space. In the cpanel, I selected `nautilus` for accessing web-disk and I was given a note:

> Note: In order for the Web Disk 
>   to work, you will need to allow 
>   port 2078 (SSL) or 2077 (non-SSL) 
>   on your computer's firewall.

As, I am unable to connect to this, i.e. on entering the given url in Nautilus address bar, it says 'Connection closed'. So, I believe the above this quoted is not correctly configured.

Please let me know, how to configure this? How to allow the given port access?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be receiving that message and you should contact your host since only they can open the ports unless you have SSH access with those rights.

Additionally ensure you check out [cpanels documentation on how to connect](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/CpanelDocs/WebDisk#Access%20a%20Web%20Disk%20Account) though your find no mention of ports. It's important to note that your not serving the files so theres no need to open your own ports and they need to be opened on the server, hence contact your host.

Comment: Exactly - SSH does port forwarding, use it to open a tunnel for MySQL, et. al., You DO NOT want to be opening these kinds of ports to public access. Run them through an SSH tunnel and we won't be viewing the Turkish Hacking League home page on your website in the near future.